# Websecurity.CreateUserAndAccount on Azure doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first, simplemembership

I have a method that registers a new user using `WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password)` The problem is that in the `UserProfile` model I have added a `GUID` Key. On my local machine this just populates an empty Guid when I call this method. On azure however, I get the following error:

```
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Key', table 'Scheduler.dbo.UserProfile'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
```

Now, I've tried to generate a new GUID in the constructor of the model, manually have the `Set{}` generate a new GUID and I get the same error.

When I try to use the CreateUserAndAccount  overload like:

```
 WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password, new { Key = Guid.NewGuid() });
```

I get the following syntax error (run time):

```
 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Key'.
```

I've spent a good part of the morning trying to figure this out and I just can't. By the way all of the above methods still result in an empty GUID `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000` and the overload gives me syntax error on my local machine.

Comment: I fixed this before by just doing a toString i.e. Guid.NewGuid().toString()

Comment: @AshleyMedway Which method did you use, and also the property accepts a GUID so I cannot give it a string.

Comment: change the property to string, also Key is a keyword so rename Key to something like UserID

Answer (score 0):

"Key" is a reserved word in SQL, it should be used in brackets like this [Key]

Since you don't have control on how WebSecurity generate the SQL query then your only option is to rename it to something like UserKey